# IPN for Recurring Payment using PayPal Payments Pro

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce shopping cart, there is no current implementation of IPN for Recurring Payment if i use PayPal Payment Pro (PayPal Direct) as Payment Method, however IPN works and change the order status only at first installment cycle but never works for second term. I want to develop this feature and spend more than 2 days on this and unable to figure out how to start. I have read all the documentation provided by PayPal but still confused. First of, if anyone tell me if IPN for Recurring Payment is supported by PayPal in case of Payment Pro (PayPal Direct) i am talking about developing this feature by writing code in asp.net MVC C# not buy buttons or etc., i am might have to use APIs? Secondly please help me to develop this feature i would really appropriate that.

Answer (score 0):

IPN does work with PPPRP (Paypal payments pro recurring payments)

And no.. you don't really *need* to write any APIs.. but you will want to in order to re-capture payments that fail, re-start recurring payments that have failed three times or more.. etc..

Sources:

> IPN is a message service that PayPal uses to notify you about events,
>   such as:
>
> [Recurring payment and subscription actions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)